# React Movie catalog

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am in the process of teaching myself React and could use a little guidance in one aspect. I am building a movie catalog as a practice project, however I am finding it difficult to change the state of my SetState with the data from my API. I am using the TMDB API. The following code shows where I make use of the API and attempt to update the UseSate.

```
const App =  () => {

    // useState hook --> Sets an an array of movies in the API in which we can Search.
    // Always use [variable, setVariable]
    // Default value of movies is an empty array --> useState([]);
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]); 

    // Setting the search bar:
    // Pass in an empty string: useState('');
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

    // async, response and data are responsible for accessing the API.
    const searchMovies = async (title) => {
        let url = ''.concat(API_URL, '&query=', searchTerm);
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        setMovies(data.Search);
    }
```

I am wanting to update the state of setMovies, so that I can display all the searched movies. I do this by:

```
{movies?.length > 0 ? (
                <div className="container">
                    {movies.map((movie) => (
                        <MovieCard movie={movie} />
                    ))}
                </div>
                ) : (
                    <div className="empty">
                    <h2>No movies found</h2>
                    </div>
                )}
```

MovieCard is a functional component that renders the poster of each movie when it is found. If not, the message "No movies found" is displayed.

For some reason I can't seem to pass the object data from the API to the MovieCard prop which is called movie.

The object data looks like this if useful:

```
{
    "adult": false,
    "backdrop_path": "/rAiYTfKGqDCRIIqo664sY9XZIvQ.jpg",
    "genre_ids": [
        12,
        18,
        878
    ],
    "id": 157336,
    "original_language": "en",
    "original_title": "Interstellar",
    "overview": "The adventures of a group of explorers who make use of a newly discovered wormhole to surpass the limitations on human space travel and conquer the vast distances involved in an interstellar voyage.",
    "popularity": 122.037,
    "poster_path": "/gEU2QniE6E77NI6lCU6MxlNBvIx.jpg",
    "release_date": "2014-11-05",
    "title": "Interstellar",
    "video": false,
    "vote_average": 8.4,
    "vote_count": 30010
}
```

Thank you in advance!
All the best, Michael

I was expecting the movie catalog to appear when I searched a movie. However, I continue to get the message "No movies Found". I have logged the data from the API to the console and it does appear when I search something.

edit: MovieCard.jsx

```
const MovieCard = ({ movie }) => {
    return (
        <div className="movie">
                    <div>
                        <p>{movie.release_date}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img
                            // if poster is N/A Than apply the specified poster in object. Else use the placeholder 
                            src = {movie.poster_path !== 'N/A' ? ''.concat('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original', movie.poster_path) : 'https://www.shortlist.com/media/imager/201905/22154-posts.article_lg.jpg'} alt = {movie.title}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {/* The <span> tag is an inline container used to mark up a part of a text, or a part of a document. */}
                        <span>{movie.original_language}</span> 
                        <h3>{movie.title}</h3>
                    </div>

                </div>
    )
}

export default MovieCard;
```

Further edit: The console log when searching for 'Interstellar'. Each element of the depicted object array consists of an object as the one shown above

[image: .]

Comment: The data that you've posted - is that the _whole_ data you're getting from the API? That's an object, and it doesn't have a `length` attribute, and you won't be able to `map` over it (as `map` is an _array_ method). If that was an _array_ of object(s) that looks like it should work.

Comment: Hi @Andy, The object I've posted is just one object of many. Each element of the [movies, setMovies] represents one object, which is why it confuses me a little as to why you can't map. Does the length attribute not specify the length of the 'movies' list?

Comment: But if the data you're getting from the API is one object (not an array) you're overriding your state with it even though you have initialised your state _as_ an array.

Comment: I can show you the data that I get from the API. It is't just one object. The request results in an array of objects based on what I search. Sorry if I'm not fully understanding you, but I'll append the console log of the requested objects to the bottom of my question.

Comment: Ah, ok - the response _is_ an object. But it has a `results` array inside it. So either `map` over `movies.results` _or_ add `data.search.results` to the state instead, and `map` over `movies` like you are at the moment. And that should do it!

Comment: Ahh that worked! Thank you so much :) Does make a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

You will need a list to display the results of the movies.map(movie):

```
{movies?.length > 0 ? (
  <div className="container">
    <ul>
      {movies.map((movie) => (
       <li key={movie.id} >
        <MovieCard movie={movie} />
       </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
) : (
  <div className="empty">
    <h2>No movies found</h2>
  </div>
  )}
```

Just to confirm: verify that MovieCard is well imported in App and that you use the {movie} prop in your MovieCard file.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Dominique! Thank you so much for your help! MovieCard is indeed well imported. I'll add it to my question so that you can see how I've defined it. What you have said does make sense, however the result doesn't change. I thought movies represents an array of all these objects, which is why it is confusing me. If you do get a chance to look at this again, I have updated my question with the MovieCard definition. Thank you!

Comment: I am in line with Andy's answer! Happy coding!